# -dorf versus -dorff as name ending

Tags: spelling

I see people with names like Something-dorf but then also Something-dorff. Why are there two f's when the actual word *Dorf* is just one f? I understand surnames can be strangely spelled, but this seems intentionally wrong.

Comment: Why does it seem intentionally wrong to you?

Comment: Because Dorf is being misspelled.

Comment: This is like asking why both "Newton" and "Newtown" exist in English. The spelling of basically the same proper noun can be different for different things because of "historical reasons". Spelling changes over time, and often names don't keep up.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea that the spelling is intentionally wrong is misled. Names and their spelling usually exist much longer than orthography. As they are treated as names and not as words, their spelling does not necessarily change when spelling rules are introduced or changed.

*Dorff* just seems to be a different historical way of spelling, as is indicated by the existing surname *Dorff*, a town called *Dorff* near Aachen, another town called  *Dorff-Platz*, another town called *Wahrendorff* in Lower Saxony. I am sure if you dig deeper, you will find more instances of this spelling.

Comment: I've heard the extra f was added to indicate aristocracy. For example, I just saw someone with the last name Wendorff. But then there is a place Wendorf in M-VP. Something intentional must have happened. So perhaps a person who is aristocratic from Wendorf goes by the name (von/zu) Wendorff? This Wendorff family is/was a Freiherr?

Comment: @147pm I have extended my answer to address the theory in your comment.

Comment: The observation that some nobility families have -dorff names might be explained by the corresponding town having adapted the name to modern spelling, while the family name was left unchanged. The observation would then be explained by nobility family names being quite old.

Answer (score -5):

Simply put, we have different ending in ablative *vom Dorfe* and nominative *das Dorf*. The way case has eroded over time, it is difficult to guess what names have meant at the outset, bit it is quite possible that *-dorf* and *-dorff* represent different layers of abstraction in different dialects, for lack of a better word. Calling it “misspelled” while miss-spelling *mispelling* is not at all justified.

Comment: "vom Dorfe" is Dativ (not Ablativ) and "-e" is the old marker for Dativ, like in "am Golde hängt, zum Golde drängt doch alles" or fixed phrases "zu Hause". A misinformation *wie sie im Buche steht*.